# What does this ".=" mean in perl

Tags: perl

while I was reading my Senior's Perl Script I stumble upon to this symbol ".=", can anyone explain what exactly its  purpose or function.

```
.=
```

Thanks!

Comment: sorry, the link you gave didn't show up in google

Comment: Also, http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Assignment-Operators

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a string concatenation operator.

```
$x = "Foo"
$x .= "bar"

print STDOUT $x;
```

Foobar

Comment: BTW, these forms like `.=` and `+=` are short hand of `a =  a . 'string'` and `a = a + number`

Answer (score 1):

`.` is the string concatenation operator, and

```
$x .= $y;
```

is short for

```
$x = $x . $y;
```

except that `$x` is only evaluated once. (This only matters for magical variables and such.)

For example,

```
>perl -E"$x = 'abc'; $x .= 'def'; say $x;"
abcdef
```

Perl operators are documented in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html).

Answer (score 0):

`.` is concatenation operator and `.=, +=` etc is a short form, so

`x+=5` means `x=x+5`

```
my $string = "Hi";
my $string2 = "Hello";
$string.=$string2; #It means $string = $string.$string2;
```

[Demo](http://ideone.com/Pn7Gfw)

Answer (score 0):

Base on @Paul's answer

assignment operators like `.=` and `+=` are short hands of

```
$a = $a . 'string';

$a = $a + number;
```